# How to add Bearer and Scope when using HttpWebRequest with XML post

Tags: c#, api, oauth

I have tried the following but still fails authentication

```
string requestXml = doc.InnerXml;
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
byte[] bytes;
bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(requestXml);
request.ContentType = "application/xml; charset=UTF-8;";
request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
request.Method = "POST";            
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {accessToken} scope=myendpoint");
```

I have also tried

```
request.Headers.Add("scope", "myendpoint");
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure "Bearer" belongs in the header and "Scope" belongs in the body. Someone will correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: but I need to submit xml as well, how would I submit scope as well as xml

Comment: I think the scope is only needed during the authentication process, once you have an access token, then it is limited to the scope(s) you requested... I checked some of my old Google API code, and it passes the scope as a URL parameter... everything I'm saying might just depend on the implementation, and is likely wrong. I probably should have left my 2 cents out of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first acquire a token via a series of HTTP requests/responses, then use this token as a bearer token in a subsequent API call (a new HTTP request/response).  The way you acquire a token depends on the protocol. If the protocol is oAuth v2 and (for example) you're doing client credentials grant type/flow, `scope` is an optional request parameter. The request might look like this:

```cs
String serviceURL = "https://blah.accesscontrol.windows.net/...";
String body = string.Format("grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&scope={2}", "<client id>","<client secret>","<scope>");

System.Net.WebRequest webRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(serviceURL);
webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
webRequest.Method = "POST";

byte[] payload = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(body);
webRequest.ContentLength = payload.Length;
using (System.IO.Stream outputStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
{
    outputStream.Write(payload, 0, payload.Length);
}
System.Net.WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse(););
// extract token from response
```

Adding a bearer token:

```cs
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
```

Comment: Turns out the api documentation was incorrect from the 3rd party, it did not require scope in the header.

Comment: I was doing this but found that I was sending the request using HTTP and something is stripping off that header if it is not sent using HTTPS.